# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'. Tokenized Strings 100% integers

Tags: python, pandas

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Users", line 50, in <module>
    length = len_c / (len_a_b - len_c) 
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py", line 65, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py", line 97, in __sub__
    return self._arith_method(other, operator.sub)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4994, in _arith_method
    self, other = ops.align_method_SERIES(self, other)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 147, in align_method_SERIES
    left, right = left.align(right, copy=False)
  File "\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4220, in align
    return super().align(
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 8825, in alig
    return self._align_series(
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 8934, in _align_series
    join_index, lidx, ridx = self.index.join(
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 690, in join
    return self._int64index.join(other, how, level, return_indexers, sort)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3669, in join
    return this.join(other, how=how, return_indexers=return_indexers)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3679, in join
    return self._join_monotonic(
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexe\base.py", line 4014, in _join_monotonic
    join_index, lidx, ridx = self._outer_indexer(sv, ov)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 219, in _outer_indexer
    return libjoin.outer_join_indexer(left, right)
  File "pandas\_libs\join.pyx", line 556, in pandas._libs.join.outer_join_indexer
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**The problem is in the line starting with dict1=**

```
b = df2.apply(set)
a = df1.apply(set)
#print('a', a.columns)
c =  pd.concat([b.apply(lambda x : s.intersection(x)) for s in a], axis=1)
len_a_b = b.apply(lambda x : len(x) +  len(a))
len_c  = c.apply(lambda x : len(x))
dict1 = {'length' : len_c / (len_a_b - len_c) , 'b' : b , 'c' : c}
```

**This is how the dataframes look like:**

```
0 [Tom, eats, pineapple]
1 [Tom, eats, pineapple]
2 [Eva, eats, apple]
3 [Eva, eats, pineapple]
Name: all, dtype: object
0 [Tom, eats, pineapple]
1 [Tom, eats, pineapple]
2 [Eva, eats, apple]
3 [Eva, eats, pineapple]
Name: sentence, dtype: object
```

**print(len_c): Length: 550, dtype: int64**

**print(len_a_b): Length: 6646, dtype: int64**

As you can see after the tokenization we have 100% integers here and still python says it doesn't.
The same function worked with the data when it weren't two whole dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
len_c  = c.apply(lambda x : len(x))
```

Use this:

```
len_c =c.apply(lambda x : len(x)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Finally:

```
dict1 = {'length' : len_c / (len_a_b - len_c) , 'b' : b , 'c' : c}
```

Comment: Okay, that did something. Now I want o put into a dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)` and the mesage is:                  `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (550,) into shape (6646,)` Can you explain?

Comment: well try `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1)` or `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1,orient='index')`

Comment: The first approach does not change anything and the second does not show the tokens anymore but only numbers. Also, I cannot order by 'length'.

Comment: try: `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1,orient='index').T`

Comment: Every result is -1.0916557161629434 or NaN even though the dataframes dont have any NaN

Comment: That's because the shape of data is different so to maintain the shape/length.The rest columns are filled by nan

Comment: OK, but I either have no result or this strange number. It does not make sense anymore mathematically even though the formula is the same. ALso, it only plots the first column of the first datafram against all of the other